# How can a Tester use Heuristics effectively to generate good test ideas?

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, test-design, testcase, test-techniques

I have tried to use Test design Heuristics to guide my strategy for test design. For instance, during exploratory test session, I use different tours like file tour, menu tours.

Can you give real-life scenarios/examples, in which testers used any heuristic technique to really create good test ideas? It would be helpful, if you could quote any techniques that were helpful in your experience.

Comment: The question is not clear and too broad, can you focus ? in the meantime here's my all time favorite for test ideas:
http://thetesteye.com/posters/TheTestEye_SourcesForTestIdeas.pdf

Comment: Hi @Rsf, well thanks for referring to the document. Well, I wanted to know that do heuristics really convert into test ideas that one can possibly use in production environment testing scenarios? I read all the "heuristics" types, but fail to use any of it *practically*. It would be great if you can perhaps edit my question to make it more clear and better for this forum! Thanks!!

Comment: I disagree with the close votes that this is "too broad". The OP is asking for some real-life examples. The last sentence about a "comprehensive list" does make it sound a bit broad but I think asking for examples is a good, reasonable question for this site.

Comment: I second what c32hedge commented.  Drop the close votes, please.  This is not _too broad_.

Comment: I agree with c32hedge too. This is a reasonably valid question.

Comment: I agree with people who vote for close. This question raises interesting discussion, however it is formulated in the way that does not allow to pick the "correct" answer.

Comment: I think most of the best questions on the site don't have a "correct" answer, but that's not what accepting an answer means--accepting just means that the accepted answer was most _helpful_. This is a _way_ better question than most of the ones that come through about XPath and Selenium debugging, and will actually be useful to future readers.

Comment: Appreciate your opinion, but I do not think so. The answer should not be just helpful but "correct" as well. Otherwise we wouldn't have "opinion based" or "too broad" closure justifications. "Helpful" answers are ranged by upvotes, but "accepted" has to be "correct" (i.e. have objective property that makes it really different from other helpful answers). OP is asking about user's experience. Who can say that the experience of person A is more representative than the experience of person B? How for example one "real life scenario" could be more representative than other?

Comment: We might want to move this to meta, but I'll just add this: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ -- note that the [help page](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) specifically says that constructive subjective questions "invite sharing experiences over opinions".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently read quite good blog post from Michael Bolton, where he used James Bach's [Heuristic Test Strategy Model](http://www.satisfice.com/tools/htsm.pdf) to generate test ideas.

That blog post has 5 parts, so do not be discouraged on first two parts: [Exploratory Testing on an API? (Part 1)](https://www.developsense.com/blog/2018/07/exploratory-testing-on-an-api-part-1/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'd call it a Heuristic exactly, but my favourite way of testing is to

- take the high level description of a test case
- ignore the detailed instructions
- try to perform the task blind, like a fresh user who's
  never been on the app / website before